# I want to select min date and time in php

Tags: php, html

My Code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="date" min ='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'max="2099-12-31"  name="InterviewDate" required>
```

What should appear in min?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the browser source when you access the page? As it stands, the min date would be the current date. If you want something different, then change it.

Comment: At first I had Date only it used to disabled past dates and today's date. @aynber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a time with the date in W3C format (example: "2018-06-07T00:00"). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="date" min ='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>T00:00'max="2099-12-31T00:00"  name="InterviewDate" required>
```